# Javascript substring and indexOf not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, substring, indexof

I have this Javascript here:

```
function getTxt(obj) {
var first = obj.innerHTML.substring(0, obj.innerHTML.indexOf('<span class=\"item2\">'));
var second = obj.innerHTML.substring(obj.innerHTML.indexOf('<span class=\"item2\">'));
var f = first.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'');
var s = second.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'');
alert(first + "\n" + second + "\n" + f + "\n" + s);
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<span class="item" onclick="getTxt(this)"><span class="item1">MyName</span><span class="item2">555-555-5555</span></span>
```

In most browsers (FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera) it will alert:

```
<span class="item1">MyName</span>
<span class="item2">555-555-5555</span>
MyName
555-555-5555
```

as expected. However, in IE9 it alerts:

```
<span class="item1">MyName</span><span class="item2">555-555-5555</span>

MyName555-555-5555
```

So it puts the vars "first" and "second" together into var "first", and puts "f" and "s" together into var "f".

I would like to know if there is anyway to correct this for IE9 (and probably other version of IE also) to work as it does in the other browsers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `obj.innerHTML.indexOf("<span class=\"item2\">")` instead of `obj.innerHTML.indexOf('<span class=\"item2\">')` notice the double quotes instead of the single

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern matching `innerHTML` is particularly a problem in IE and is generally a bad idea.  IE often does NOT return to you the same HTML that was originally in the page.  It often requotes or removes quotes, changes the order of attributes, changes case, etc...  IE is clearly reconstituting the HTML rather than give you back what was originally in the page.  As such, you cannot reliably pattern match innerHTML in IE.  There are some specific things you can probably match (the start of tags), but you can't expect attributes to be in a specific spot or to have a specific format.

If you `console.log(obj.innerHTML)` in IE, you will likely see what I'm talking about.  It will look different.

A more robust solution is to use the DOM functions to navigate the specific elements or CSS selectors to find specific objects and then change attributes or innerHTML on a single specific element.  Let the DOM navigation find the right element for you rather than parsing the HTML yourself.

If you provide a desired before and after sample of the HTML and describe what you're trying to accomplish, folks here can probably help you get the job done with DOM manipulation rather than HTML parsing.

I don't know which selector libraries you have available to you or which browsers you're targeting, but in jQuery, you could do this like this:

```
function getText(obj) {
    return $(obj).find(".item1").text();
}
```

In plain javascript, in IE8 and above and all other modern browsers, you can use this:

```
function getText(obj) {
    return obj.querySelectorAll(".item1").innerHTML;
}
```

If you had to support back to IE6 or IE7, I'd suggest getting the Sizzle library and use that for your queries:

```
function getText(obj) {
    return Sizzle(".item1", obj)[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you mean. It capitalizes the tag name and removes the quotes from around the spans class. Well atleast I know what is causing it now. Thank you.

Comment: I have a list of the spans with names and phone numbers in them. What I am doing is when one is clicked get the name from the span that was clicked (the var "f" in this case) to be passed on to open a specific page.

Comment: @Tomjr260 - I've added several code examples for how to fetch the name using DOM access rather than HTML parsing.

Comment: Very good. I can use jQuery so I will probably use that solution. I would like to support as many browsers as possible so I may also look into Sizzle, or will jQuery work for IE6 also? Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: @Tomjr260 - jQuery uses Sizzle internally as it's selector engine and will work with all browsers down to IE6.  If jQuery is available, you can just use jQuery for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of "Quirky mode" in Internet Explorer. It's a huge pain in the ass, but you can disable it in IE DevTools, or by adding this metatag to your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```